# Decision region when bit/symbol mapped to multiple points on the constellation

Tags: constellation-diagram

Let $x$ be 0, +1 or -1 with probability $1/2$, $1/4$, $1/4$, $\cdots$

What is the decision region?

I was asked this question during an interview. Can someone please give me a hint or source (from a conceptual point of view) to solve these types of problems?

Comment: this is a bit broad. We don't know where you're stuck. For example, we don't know whether you understand what a decision region is, and *why* you want one. The answer to *all* engineering problems is "to fulfill the purpose, as good and efficiently as possible"; but it's up to you to define "purpose", "good" and "efficiently".

Comment: also, your title seems to be disconnected from your question. $x$ takes *one* of three values, not multiple values. Honestly, this question is a bit too broad – we weren't there in your interview, we don't have the context, and to top it of, interview questions rarely are just to test a candidate's knowledge (otherwise, it would make no sense to ask now), but to see how they work *on their own* when presented with something they don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is actually a perfectly valid question intended to check your approach to poorly-defined problems where you need to come up with a framework that allows making some reasonable approaches to an answer.

You are given a signal constellation of three unequally-likely points on the real line and asked for decision regions.  Well, it is reasonable to assume that the noise has a continuous distribution that is symmetric about $0$ (though there are some people on this forum who have questioned whether it is necessarily true that white noise is a zero-mean process).  So, if the channel input is $x \in \{-1, 0, +1\}$ and the output is $y = x+n$ where the pdf of $n$ is an even function, the decision regions are necessarily of the form
\begin{align}
\text{If }~ y < -A, & ~\text{decide that } &-1 ~ \text{was transmitted}\\
\text{If }~ |y| \leq A, & ~\text{decide that } &0 ~ \text{was transmitted}\\
\text{If }~ y > A, & ~\text{decide that } &+1 ~ \text{was transmitted}\\
\end{align}
for some positive number $A$. In other words, the decision regions for $-1, 0, +1$ are $(-\infty, -A), [-A,A],(A,\infty)$ respectively. The corresponding error probabilities are
\begin{align}
P_{e,-1} &= P(y \geq -A \mid x = -1) = P(n \geq 1-A),\\
P_{e,+1} &= P(y \leq +A \mid x = +1) = P(n \leq A-1),\\
P_{e,0} &= P(|y| > A \mid x = 0) = P(|n| > A),\\
\end{align}
where we note that the symmetry of the pdf of $n$ implies that $P_{e,-1} = P_{e,+1}$. As to what $A$ should be, it depends on what the distribution of $n$ is, and also what would be a desirable outcome. We could try to choose $A$ so as to make the three error probabilities equal (minimax approach) or, since the hypotheses have known unequal *a priori* probabilities, we could try to choose $A$ to minimize the *expected* (a.k.a. average) error probability $\bar{P}_e= \frac 12 P_{e,0} + \frac 14P_{e,+1} + \frac 14P_{e,-1} = \left.\left. \frac 12 \right(P_{e,0}+P_{e,+1}\right)$.

Comment: we used to call this "M-ary communication".  I guess this would be trinary communication.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Some people prefer ternary over trinity